# ошибка в конструкции if

Tags: python

при запуске выделяется красным равно, и функция run не работает
пыталась убирать скобки и убирать пробел в конструкции

```
print("*** =1" + "**** = 2" + "***** = 3" + "****** = 4")
ID = int(input("Введите ваш ID: "))
if ID = 1
    print("Гони 36 сумов")
elif ID = 2:
    print("Че пацаны, аниме(манга\n руманга\n манхва\n OELманга\n маньхуа?")
elif ID = 3:
    print("Свали в туман, ежик")
elif ID = 4:
    print("Старикам вход воспрещен")
else:
    print("сли не они тогда вали")
```

(имена замазаны)``

Comment: Сравнение выполняется оператором ==, а не =

Comment: Помимо того, что сравнении выполняется другим оператором, Вы ещё пропустили двоеточие после первого условия

Answer (score 1):

1. После каждого if, необходимо ставить : У вас в строке "if ID = 1" его нет
2. Для сравнения, необходимо ставит два =, например "ID == 2"

Исправленный код будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
print("*** =1" + "**** = 2" + "***** = 3" + "****** = 4")
ID = int(input("Введите ваш ID: "))
if ID == 1:
    print("Гони 36 сумов")
elif ID == 2:
    print("Че пацаны, аниме(манга\n руманга\n манхва\n OELманга\n маньхуа?")
elif ID == 3:
    print("Свали в туман, ежик")
elif ID == 4:
    print("Старикам вход воспрещен")
else:
    print("сли не они тогда вали")
```

Про функцию run ничего не понятно, в коде её нет